# Execute current Python script in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python program which I have made work in both Python 2 and 3, and it has more functionality in Python 3 (using new Python 3 features).

My script currently starts `#!/usr/bin/env python`, as that seems to be the mostly likely name for a python executable. However, what I'd like to do is "if python3 exists, use that, if not use python".

I would prefer not to have to distribute multiple files / and extra script (at present my program is a single distributed python file).

Is there an easy way to run the current script in python3, if it exists?

Comment: So you already check inside the script if it is being executed by Python 2 or 3, but need an external script to check if Python 3 exists?

Comment: I would like to not run an external script. What I (think) I want is a way to add to the top of my script "is this python2, but python3 is installed? If so, re-exec the script in python3".

Comment: So you plan to make this program for users, that don't know how to run shell script? If not, I would just wrap the program in the shell script I posted below

Answer (score 1):

Another better method modified from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070516/conditional-shebang-line-for-different-versions-of-python) is to check the `sys.version`:

```
import sys
py_ver = sys.version[0]
```

Original answer: May not be the best method, but one way to do it is test against a function that only exist in one version of Python to know what you are running off of.

```
try:
    raw_input
    py_ver = 2

except NameError:
    py_ver = 3

if py_ver==2:
   ... Python 2 stuff

elif py_ver==3:
   ... Python 3 stuff
```

Comment: Might need to call raw_input as a function (`raw_input()`)

Comment: It would return `<built-in function raw_input>`, so no, it won't fail if on Python 2.7.  But the `sys.version` is definitely a much easier way to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Try with version_info from sys package

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't quite get what you want. I understood: You want to look if there is Python 3 installed on the Computer and if so, use it. Inside the script you can check the version with `sys.version` as Idlehands mentioned. To get the latest version you might want to use a small bash script like this

```
py_versions=($(ls /usr/bin | grep 'python[0-9]\.[0-9]$'))
${py_versions[-1]} your_script.py
```

This searches the output of `ls` for all python versions and stores them in `py_versions`. Thankfully the output is already sorted, so the last element in the array will be the latest version.